# Deploy several container to azure using docker compose

Tags: azure, docker

I'm have created a service that uses several contanainers, the basic structure of my project is:

```
|--maindir:
   |--app1:
      |--dockerfile1
      |--proyect folder...
   |--app2:
      |--dockerfile2
      |--proyect folder...
   |--app3:
      |--dockerfile3
      |--proyect folder...
```

Currently what I'm doing to deploy each of the containers is:

1) Use docker . build to create the image
2) Tag the image and push it to the azure registry
3) Create the container out of the image on the azure registry:

```
az container create \
    --resource-group mygroup \
    --name manager \
    --image core.azurecr.io/samples/manager \
    --registry-login-server xxx \
    --registry-password xxx   \
    --registry-username xxx \
    --ports  5000 5100 \
    --memory 3 \
    --cpu 1 \
    --ip-address public \
    --dns xxx \
    --azure-file-volume-account-name xxx \
    --azure-file-volume-account-key  xxx \
    --azure-file-volume-share-name xxx \
    --azure-file-volume-mount-path /xxx
```

I need each of those settings, like the DNS, the volume, ram... for each of the containers.

Is it possible to do this using a docker compose.yml file?

I have found this in example in the Azure documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

But that one asumes the image is already in the azure registry, which is not the case for me.
If I have to create and push the image one by one, it does not makes much difference to use the docker compose just at the end.

Comment: Any more questions? Do you solve the problem? More help or you can accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you use the Azure CLI command `az container create` it means you create the Azure Container Instance, but when you refer to the docker-compose file in the document you provide with the link, it means the Azure Web App. In other words, there are two different Azure Service.

In addition, whenever you use the docker images, you need to create the images yourself and find a registry to push the images to, no matter the ACR or the Docker hub.

And if you use the docker-compose, it can help you build all the images at one time. You only need to create the docker-compose file and set the `build` options with the value Dockerfile path. You can take a look at the docker-compose [example](https://lockmedown.com/docker-devs-multiple-containers-docker-compose/).